`GetProcessGroupAffinity` fails with `ERROR_NOACCESS` if memory pointed to by `GroupArray` is not aligned to 4 bytes
GetProcessGroupAffinity requires the memory for [out]     PUSHORT GroupArray to be overaligned. Is this (bug?) documented anywhere? Is this even a bug? The only mention I could find is a comment inside fio's Windows CPU affinity code:
    /*
     * GetProcessGroupAffinity() seems to expect more than the natural
     * alignment for a USHORT from the area pointed to by current_groups so
     * arrange for maximum alignment by allocating via malloc()
     */

Reproduction:
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    USHORT GroupCount = 1;
    alignas(4) USHORT GroupArray[2];

    auto status = GetProcessGroupAffinity(GetCurrentProcess(), &GroupCount, GroupArray);
    auto a = GetLastError();
    std::cout << a << ' ' << status << '\n';
    
    status = GetProcessGroupAffinity(GetCurrentProcess(), &GroupCount, GroupArray + 1);
    a = GetLastError();
    std::cout << a << ' ' << status << '\n';
}

g++ a.cpp -static && ./a prints
0 1
998 0

If anything, let this post serve as documentation for people searching for this issue (I intentionally worded the title this way to facilitate this, please don't change it)

yes, ProcessGroupInformation for NtQueryInformationProcess really return error STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT if GroupArray not aligned on 4*x

This bug was fixed in Windows 11 last year, for the record.
